# How to use Custom Connector search from backend with Combobox?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, power-apps-custom-connector

I have a problem setting ComboBox items property.

I found I can use `Office365User.SearchUser({searchTerm: ComboBox1.SearchText, top:20});`

and then It can search from Office365User Connector.

but this way can't apply to my Custom connector.

I already create a custom connector and add actions like `MyConnector.SearchCategory({keyword: ComboBox1.SearchText});` 
And then, I set it to my ComboBox items, but it will alert an error message:

**Behavior function in a non-behavior property. You can't use this property to change values elsewhere in the app**

I think setting `Collect(CategoryList, MyConnector.SearchCategory({keyword: ComboBox1.SearchText}));` on the OnSelect event is not the right answer for me.

Could you tell me how can I do now? :'(

I want to search from searchText and wait for the list from API.

Comment: Can you specify why Collect is not an option for you? Also, users might want to change their search terms.  Therefore ClearCollect is recommended instead of Collect.

Comment: @mmikesy90 User can search when it typing. But doesn't have any event like onSearchChange or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

1. Disable the searching functionality in your combobox.
2. Create a separate text input for the users to enter search terms. Use the ClearCollect() function in the text input's OnChange property to load O365U results to a collection. Be sure to set DelayOutput to true, otherwise your app will spam API calls for every character entered.
3. Set the collection to the Combobox.Items property.